# Magento Price Range Filters

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I would like to ask a question:

I have a problem with the price ranges filters in the search page, and it shows many un-real ranges that I don’t know why.

check this page for example:

https://znbaq.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=bebe

it seems that it is showing the price ranges for all of the products on my website !

Can you please advise a solution ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: but this might be related to programming also

Comment: I can't see anything in your question about programming. It doesn't matter if the answer may involve programming - that would just mean that the question isn't specifically about programming and hence it is off-topic for the site.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reduce range interval from backend and then reindex attributes, index_price and fulltext. Hope it works.

Answer (score 0):

try reindexing product attributes and price index.